# Generating iterator instead of list in recursion

Tags: scala, collections, stream, iteration, ondemand

There is [a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4525435) which says that we should Stream/View or Iterate our  collections to make them on-demand. It is clear. I just do not understand what should I apply the `.view` or `.iterate` to in the following demo

```
val l1 = List("10", "00", "0")
def gen(depth: Int): Iterable[String] = if (depth == 1) l1 else {
    for (sub <- gen(depth-1); item <- List(depth + sub, sub+sub, sub)) yield item
}
```

Should I apply them to `gen(depth-1)` or to `List(depth+..)`?

By the way, should I inline `l1` in the `(depth == 1) l1 else`? It is not used anywhere else. I just afraid that it would create a new list for every leaf.

Answer (score 0):

I would have to try it, but I would say `List(depth+..).view`, since you wont use the same values more than once.I think it will give you a sort of DFS traversal given the recursion you have there.

And yeah, I would not inline it but live `l1` like that. I would even do `val l1 = List("10", "00", "0").view`.